# Probability find color of iphone

Tags: probability

I have a question as following:

There are n customers forming a line inside Apple store, half of them have Rose iPhone and half have Gray iPhone, shuffled randomly. You are challenged to predict iPhone color of the next person exiting the store, where they will exit one by one.

At any point, if you correctly predict the iPhone color of exiting customer as Rose, you win. You can choose to skip any number of guesses and see their iPhone color until you decide to guess that the next iphone color is Rose. You will only win if predict the color to be Rose and people exiting the store carries a Rose iPhone.

I want to ask that is there a method that has better chances of winning than $\frac{1}{2}$, and if there is no such method, why is that?

Thank you

Comment: If I can only win then the phone is pink, who/what stops me from eternally guessing pink? (winning probability 1)

Comment: @mdave16 Hi, you will only have one chance to guess; so there's no way you can eternally guess Rose Gold

Comment: You look at $n-1$ people and you'll get $a$ rose and $a-1$ grey, guess grey. 100% win

Comment: @JacobClaassen You will only win if guess a person exiting has a Rose Gold iPhone and the person actually has a Rose Gold iPhone. Guessing grey correctly does not count as win. Also, I think if you let $n-1$ people go, and guess the $n_{th} $ people, the probability of that being Rose Gold is still $1/2$

Comment: what if you wait until there's more RG's left than SG's? There should be greater than 50% chance for it to happen and it'll result in greater than 50% chance of guessing correctly.

Comment: @JacobClaassen This might happen. But it could also be that people with RG and SG exit sequentially. Meaning one RG person exit, and next person exiting is SG, then RG, and continue. Therefore, what you suggested might not be generalized

Comment: @Parker, the chance that at some point {RG left} > {SG left} is greater than 50%

Comment: @JacobClaassen Could you please show why this is the case?

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1932790/420432

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let the exiting customers be labeled by numbers $1$ through to $N$, where $N$ is even. It is given that exactly half of them have rose colored phones and the rest half have grey colored phones. Consider the proposition:
\begin{align}
R_i\equiv\textrm{The exiting customer $i$ has rose colored phone}
\end{align}
The negation of the above proposition means that customer $i$ has grey colored phone. Suppose $(n-1)$ customers have exited, $1\leq n\leq N$, and you guess that the $n$-th customer holds a rose colored phone. What is the probability that your guess is right? That depends on the color of the phones carried by the $(n-1)$ customers who have exited and which cannot be known in advance.

Let $m$ among the $(n-1)$ customers who have exited have rose colored phones. Since there are $N/2$ rose colored phones in all, there are $C_m^{N/2}$ ways of selecting $m$ rose colored phones. Rest of the customers who exited have grey colored phones, and there are $C_{n-1-m}^{N/2}$  ways of selecting $(n-1-m)$ grey colored phones. There are therefore $C_m^{N/2}\times C_{n-1-m}^{N/2}$ ways of having $m$ rose colored phones among $(n-1)$ customers who exited. Here we adopt the convention that $C_x^y=0$ if $x>y$.

Therefore the probability that exactly $m$ among $(n-1)$ customers who exited have rose colored phones is:
\begin{align}
P(m|n-1)=\frac{C_m^{N/2}\times C_{n-1-m}^{N/2}}{\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\left( C_k^{N/2}\times C_{n-1-k}^{N/2}\right)},\quad 0\leq m\leq \textbf{min}(n-1,N/2)
\end{align}
and zero otherwise.

Given that $(n-1)$ customers exited with $m$ rose colored phones, the probability that your guess about the $n$-th customer will be correct is:
\begin{align}
P(R_n|(m,n-1))=\frac{N/2-m}{N-(n-1)},\quad 0\leq m\leq \textbf{min}(n-1,N/2)
\end{align}
and zero otherwise.

Therefore the unconditional probability that your guess for $n$-th customer will be correct is by Bayes theorem:
\begin{align}
P(R_n)&=\sum_{m=0}^{\textbf{min}(n-1,N/2)}P(m|n-1)P(R_n|(m,n-1))\\
&=\sum_{m=0}^{\textbf{min}(n-1,N/2)}\left( \frac{C_m^{N/2}\times C_{n-1-m}^{N/2}}{\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\left( C_k^{N/2}\times C_{n-1-k}^{N/2}\right)}\times \frac{N/2-m}{N-(n-1)}\right)
\end{align}

I have tried a few values of even $N$ and $P(R_n)=0.5$ always, no matter which customer you guess (i.e. for any $n$ such that $1\leq n\leq N$). I am not sure if there is an intuitive explanation for this. Also there must be some simplification for the expression above that reduces it to $1/2$ although I couldn't figure it out.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation.

Comment: I'm afraid @Deep you've stretched that too much. The conditional probability you've found previously, cancels the effect of Bayes Theorem. It could be simply explained as two colors with equal probabilities, means a success rate of 1/2. Since correctly guessing gray is not counted as a win, there will always be a success rate of 1/2